# React Router Dom Dynamic linking gives wrong data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to make a dynamic project page using react router dom v6, using params gives the right id in console, but the project displayed is wrong, heres an example:

[image: example of displaced data]

The "id: 7" is the project one and wrong, but the "6" below is the params id which is the correct one.

Here's the project page code:

```
export function ProjectPage() {
  const {projectId} = useParams();
  const project = filterData[projectId]
  const {title, mediaUrl} = project;
  console.log(project, projectId)

  return (
    <div className={"project-page-body"}>
      <div className={"project-page-title"}>
        <h1 className={"project-item-title"}>{title}</h1>
        <p className={"description"}>
          Lorem ipsum filler text for project description.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className={"project-page-image"}>
          <img src={mediaUrl} style={{width: "80vw", height: "auto" }}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}´´´
```

Comment: can you add what filterData is doing?

Comment: Please edit question to include all relevant details, data, and code, so we've complete context for what is being compared. The route params are ***always*** string type, and the `id` property you mention is a number. Ensure that you are always using type-safe equality checks. Based on your answer below you should convert the `id` property to a string, i.e. `filterData.find((project) => String(project.id) === projectId)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future notices, the solution was turning projectId into an integer.

Here's the working code:

```
 const { projectId } = useParams();
  const [project, setProject] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setProject(
      filterData.find((project) => project.id === parseInt(projectId))
    );
  }, [projectId]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Id(not paramsId) is a number type but paramsId(not Id) is a string type.
You passed projectId, which is a string type, so you need to convert projectId to string type using `toString()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although converting it into string wasn't a working solution it gave me the idea to turn it into an integer, which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have done "const project = filterData[projectId]" which means projectId will act as index fot filterData array.So as index always starts from 0 so the next project is displayed.

So you can make it as "const project = filterData[projectId-1]"